# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class in ZxingScan library

Tags: android, zxing

I have used ZxingScan library,and I had defined

> "com.google.zxing.client.android.encode.EncodeActivity" and
>   "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity"

in AndroidManifest.xml of my project.

User reporting the following issue :

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {a.b.c/com.google.zxing.client.android.PreferencesActivity};

But when I tested the app, no such problem comes.
I am not able to recognize the problem.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you properly imported your library project or jar file??

Comment: Have you using scanner via android-integrator or inject ZXing's code in your project? In first case maybe user has not installed valid BarcodeScanner app

Answer (score 0):

I find out the solution.
My project import "com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity" (which is an explicit Activity).
This explicit Activity also import "com.google.zxing.client.android.PreferencesActivity" (which is also an explicit activity for my project).

**ActivityNotFoundException will come always whenever CaputureActivity calls PreferencesActivity, otherwise it will not show any exception.**